# Текст из ресурса String не отображается в TextView

Tags: android, android-studio

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <TextView


        android:text="@string/zagal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#C9CC85"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#455B2A"/>

</ScrollView>
```

В ресурсе String содержится текст, скопированный из документа Ворд. В результате на дисплее узкая полоса самого контейнера и нет текста. Если пишу текст в ресурс вручную, то он отбражается. Подскажите заклинание пожалуйста.

Comment: Загляните в файл ресурсов, И уберите двойные кавычки из скопированного текста.

Comment: там нет кавычек

Comment: Покажите файл String.xml Ваших ресурсов

Comment: zagalni - внимательнее, не то имя пытаетесь вывести android:text="@string/zagal"

Comment: нет, там все в порядке, это я намеренно убрал часть символов здесь

Comment: Покажите файл ресурсов

Comment: <string name="zagal">Попросить пациента лечь и расположить руки вдоль тела.

</string>

Comment: Проверьте локализацию. У вас в ресурсе красным не подчеркивается?

Comment: нет, не подчеркивается

Comment: Проверьте ресурс на какой он язык, и сделайте два ресурса, русский и английский. В обоих пропишите стринг

Comment: При копировании из всякой дичи типа ворда может копироваться всякая дичь (спец. символы оформления текста, например). Проверить в этом ли дело довольно просто - скопируйте текст из ворда и вставьте в какой-нибудь человеческий текстовый редактор. Например Notepad++ (если под видной сидите). Там вы должны будете увидеть есть ли что-то помимо текста в том, что вы копируете. Если что-то будет - надо будет думать как вам организовать процесс переноса теста из ворда. Идеальным вариантом будет запросить не вордовский документ, а просто `txt` файл и/или попробовать самостоятельно конвертнуть

Comment: У меня уже просто крыша едет. Форматнул в тхт, нет ничего, кроме текста. Копирую одну строку, текст на вьюшке есть, копирую больше, нет ничего. Пишу от руки в одну строку, есть, только нажмешь Enter, все исчезает.

Comment: Хм... Т.е. с переносом строк что-то не так? А если вы многострочный текст копирнёте куда-то вне (например хотя бы и сюда, на сайт, в форму ввода вопроса/ответа/коммента) и потом обратно копирнёте в студию? Ещё можно попробовать обернуть содержимое string тэга в CDATA. Примерно так: `<string name="my_string"><![CDATA[Your long text here]]></string>`

Comment: Спасибо вам за советы. Пробовал уже и так и эдак, в одну строку, хоть убейся. А текста несколько страниц.

Comment: И всё же - можете максимально однозначно описать проблему? Лично мне всё ещё не вполне она ясна. Возможно даже, дело не в ворде, а сама студия глючит. Я правильно понял, что даже если вы просто перенос строки в тексте внутри ресурса ставите вручную, без копирования, то текст полностью не отображается внутри TextView ? Может, тут даже какая-то проблема в разметке.

Comment: Совершенно верно, даже если внутри стринга делаю вручнуб перенос, вьюшка тут же схлопывается. Сейчас добавил текст вручную, выстроил в одну строку, в студии отображается, на устройстве вместо текста увидел string is too large.

Comment: Угу... Попробуйте все переносы строк заменять на символ переноса строки: `\n`. И не весь текст так попробовать, а часть (на случай, если проблема не одна и часть проблемы - реально очень длинный текст) Т.е. типа так `<string name="test">firstLine\nsecondLine</string>`

Comment: Пробовал и так и эдак. С длиной текста все ясно, вопрос решаемый, а вот с переносом реально загадка.

Comment: А как вы проверяете, что не работает - в предпросмоторщике студии или не реальном девайсе? Возможно, у вас в разметке что-то не то? Если текст выводить просто в активити, где вся разметка это TextView с размерами во весь экран - то же самое будет?

Comment: тестирую и на реальном устройстве и на штатном в студии, эффект везде одинаковый, разметка скролл, внутри него текствью, всё

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте перегрузить студию и открыть xml в котором должна отображаться строка с текстом и вы увидите текст который который вы написали как показано на скрине значит с отображением текста все норм. Значит проблема либо в разметке либо в самом активити или фрагменте. Значит тут предоставьте весь код разметки и активити.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: там все ок, спасибо